# Why do I get the error in my acceptance test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing

Tell  me please,why does it happen?

I can't understand, if I write:

```
feature "Article Creation" do

#here i write (:all)

before(:all) do
  sign_up_helper
end
```

I get the error:

```
 Article Creation allows user to visit to creating article page
 Failure/Error: fill_in :article_title, :with => 'test_title'

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field :article_title
```

or

```
1) Article Creation allows user to visit to article page
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content I18n.t('articles.articles_new')
   expected to find text "New Article:" in "Toggle navigation Blog Rails New Contacts Sign in --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters controller: devise/sessions action: new {\"controller\"=>\"devise/sessions\", \"action\"=>\"new\"} nil You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. Sign in: Email Password Remember me Sign up Forgot your password?"
```

but, if I write:

```
feature "Article Creation" do

 #here i write(:each)

 before(:each) do
   sign_up_helper
 end
```

It's Ok. All tests works. My question -**WHY?**

This is my **test**:

```
*#before all test visitor signs up
#here I've changed :all and :each*
feature "Article Creation" do
before(:all) do
  sign_up_helper
end

scenario "allows user to visit to article page" do
  visit new_article_path

  expect(page).to have_content I18n.t('articles.articles_new')
end

scenario "allows user to visit to created article page" do
  visit new_article_path


  fill_in :article_title, :with => 'test_title'
  fill_in :article_text, :with => 'example_text'
  click_button 'Save Article'

  expect(page).to have_content 'example_text'
end
```

This is **sign_up_helper method**:

```
#spec/support/session_helper.rb
def sign_up_helper
  visit new_user_registration_path

  fill_in :user_email, :with => 'user@example.com'
  fill_in :user_username, :with => 'mike'
  fill_in :user_password, :with => 'secure123!@#'
  fill_in :user_password_confirmation, :with => 'secure123!@#'

    click_button 'Sign up'
end
```

This is **html form:**

```
<p>
  <label for="article_title">Title</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="article[title]" id="article_title" />
  </p>

<p>
  <label for="article_text">Text</label><br/>
  <textarea name="article[text]" id="article_text">
  </textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment for each test is set anew, I think. New session, cookies, etc. In many cases, even brand new users are generated. So one "global" login is not possible.

Even if it were possible, it would still be a problem, as it introduces **spec order dependency** which is bad. Imagine that one of your specs logs user out. Then each subsequent spec would fail, because user is not logged in anymore.

To prevent this, make sure that each spec sets its own environment as it needs it (user logins, method stubs, etc.), without relying on side-effects from previously executed specs (which may or may not persist).

Comment: Do `before :each`.